# Angular 9. Retry the function after re-authorization and with a new session

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

I have a function that receives data

```
getAll(params) {
  return this.http.get(url).pipe(map(data => {
    return data
  })
})
```

In this.http.get i use session id for auth. How can i call relogin function with post request and retry my getAll() if my session died

Comment: It all depends on your architecture. You should either provide a stack blitz code or provide more robust description of your problem.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/al8K9D

Answer (score 0):

I think you refeer the refresh token method. Try with this link https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/05/22/angular-9-jwt-authentication-with-refresh-tokens
but you should use OAuth2 or similar with Implicit flow.

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
            if ([401, 403].includes(err.status) && this.authenticationService.userValue) {
                // auto logout if 401 or 403 response returned from api
                // this.authenticationService.logout();
                // Or call your get token and try it again
            }

            const error = (err && err.error && err.error.message) || err.statusText;
            console.error(err);
            return throwError(error);
        }))
    }
}
```